# What is meant by a "First Class Protocol"

Tags: semantics

The Node.js about page describes HTTP as being a "first class protocol" within node.js.  What does this mean?

http://nodejs.org/about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"First class" usually means that it has extensive support and will probably supported for quite some time before being dropped. It also means many things in the framework will bend to allow this support.

Comment: Semantically like "first class travel" then, thanks!

Comment: @John: Not exactly.